# Lost planet novel from the 80s or older

Tags: story-identification

Deserted planet with giant shopping towers for malls and distant crying banshees: I only remember the person was male and everybody else already left. Something about that story stayed with me, I’d love to read it again

Comment: That's not much to go on. Maybe Alain Dorémieux' short story [Seul en haut de la tour bientôt prête à crouler](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1373850). The narrator is inhabiting a decrepit tower in the desert, but on Earth, maybe in Paris. It is the end (not available on the Internet, I looked).

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Just a wild guess based on a planet where everyone has left, could this possibly be "Dying of the Light" by George R R Martin (pub 1977 so timeframe fits)

Answer (score 3):

Oh wow. "Dying of the Light"—that’s it!!!
Thank you so very much, and kind regards.

Comment: It's great that you found the answer, but you should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can accept your answer.